# C++ Regex Help for create a code for replace special caracter among letters (all letters but not last)

Tags: c++, regex, ruby

if i use this code :

```
  std::string s ("ABCDE");
  std::regex e ("([A-Z])");   

  // using string/c-string (3) version:
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"$1|");
```

my output is :

```
A|B|C|D|E|
```

but i want only:

```
A|B|C|D|E
```

Help me pls with c++ code

Comment: You have C++ code, not Ruby,  why? You mention special characters, but  `ABCDE` has only letters. `[A-Z]` only matches uppercase ASCII letters. What are you actually doing?

Comment: What is caracter?

Comment: Any letters.... pls see example

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a Regex for this.

```
str = "ABCDE"
puts str.chars.join("|") # => A|B|C|D|E
```

Comment: chars in c++ dont exists

Comment: @lago You asked for Ruby code. Later you changed to C++. We can see the edit history.

Answer (score 1):

```
"ABCDE".gsub(/(.)(?!\z)/, '\1|')
 #=> "A|B|C|D|E"
```

The regular expression matches any character and saves it to capture group 1. This is followed by a negative lookahead that prevents the match from being followed by the end of the string. Each match is replaced by the contents of capture group 1 followed by a pipe.

Comment: in c++, dont job it

Comment: I (and I expect @steenstag) can think of only one reason you would provide a Ruby tag: that you would be interested in answers for Ruby on the assumption that translating them to C++ would be straightforward. Moreover, I have provided a regular expression that should work equally well in C++.

Answer (score 0):

ok thx all , this is the solution

```
  std::string s ("ABCDE");
  std::regex e ("(.)(?!$)");  
  std::cout << std::regex_replace (s,e,"$1|");
```

output is :

```
A|B|C|D|E
```

thx Cary Swoveland i used to (?!.$)
    and it did not work because I used to "." . 
    Seeing your script I realized the error, 
    obviously it also works with ([A-Z])